# What configuration entries are changed through the graphical options interface?

Tags: firefox

I use a localized version of Firefox where preferences menu entries have localized names. When I'm discussing Firefox on international forums, it's hard to tell people what options I alter, since the names of the entries in every localized version of the browser are different.

Is there an exhaustive list of the `about:config` entries that can be changed from the graphical preferences menu; something I can use as a reference for translating my localized names?

Comment: Not eveything in about:config is accessible from the graphical options dialogs. Tell us more about what you're trying to do and how you've tried to solve it so far.

Comment: Sorry, Jonathan, I can't tell you the exact option I want to change since you sure have another name for it : ) See my update.

Comment: Yes, but what are you trying to _do_? What behavior does Firefox exhibit now, and what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: I want to know the exact list of the **standard** options names I can change from the firefox's GUI preferences menu. I need information, not a solution.

Comment: I edited the question to try to make it better fit what I think you're asking. It looks like an interesting question if I've understood it correctly. If the edit was all wrong, tell us how, and that will help too.

Comment: Perhaps the [mozillaline wiki](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Category:Configuration) has those descriptions written. However I wouldn't expect it to be listed (you would have to search and correlate)

Comment: Just a thought: In the English version I'm able to open Firefox Options/Preferences, and clicking **Help** on each tab of the Options mini-window opens the relevant English help page @ mozilla.org with the English names/terms/help for the particular Options tab's settings. Perhaps this would be the same for all the supported languages that also have the relevant help pages/sites.

Comment: Does anyone actually have an (up-to-date) answer for this years-old question? I would like the same information, but for a separate reason (so that I can determine what changes to make in my `firefox.cfg` file to update the settings for all profiles).